# Distinct 3 columns and 4th column with sum

Tags: oracle, sum, distinct

how can I select in a Oracle DB all columns but some of them `DISTINCT`.
I have columns A,B,C that I want distinct and column D that I want the sum of the rows.

```
A   B   C   D
1   2   3   10
1   2   3   20
1   2   4   1000
```

And I want the result

```
A   B   C   D
1   2   3   30
1   2   4   1000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy-peasy:

```
select a,b,c,sum(d)
from yourtable
group by a,b,c;
```

Probably too simple for this site, to be honest.